# Simple question from brain dead. Regex in Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

G'day.  I just can't seem to get something simple to work!

I have a directory structure

```
myapp    
   app
      server
          api.py
      client
          dist  
          node_modules  
          package.json  
          src  
          webpack.config.js 
smartForm
    smartform.js 
morestuff
    morestuff.js
```

Now in the React client of myapp, I want to use JSX code from globalstuff but it is not being transpiled.  It seems like it should be an easy regex on include: but for the life me I can't get it!
Help appreciated!

Example asked for!  Thanks for looking!

EDITED

```
ERROR in /disk/dev/www/smartForm/smartForm.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (244:16)

  242 |         }
  243 |         
> 244 |         return( <div>
      |                 ^
  245 |                     {formOut}
  246 |                 </div>
  247 |         );

 @ ./src/containers/people_new_edit.js 23:17-62
 @ ./src/routes.js
 @ ./src/components/app.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8888 webpack/hot/dev-server webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8888 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I want to use smartForm from several client applications.

My webpack is like this:  EDITED.

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8888',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.css$/,
      include: /style/,
      loaders: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'less-loader']
      },
    {
      test: /\.js?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include:[ 
                /src/,
                path.resolve(__dirname,'../','../','../','smartForm')
      ],
      loaders: 'react-hot-loader/webpack!babel-loader'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './dist',
    port: 8888,
    hot: true
  }
};
```

I hope that is clearer!  It seems simple, but I can't get it!
The include is being pulled in, but the JSX is not being transpiled.
Cheers.

I changed the REGEX to a string.  Same result.  The JSX is not being transpiled.  I changed my directory description to make it clearer.  Ta.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, maybe example can help

Comment: I think you don't have to use a regex, you can just quote the string to make it easier: `"../../../smartForm"` - but that path doesn't appear in your file tree?

Comment: Why the markdown?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your regex string, use `path.resolve(__dirname, '../', '../', '../', 'smartForm')`

Comment: Same error.  Unexpected token on the <div>. but thanks.  Worth a try.  Someone else MUST be sharing utility code by now?!!!

Comment: Does your `smartForm` module get transpiled properly if you put it in your `src` directory instead of its current location?

Comment: Yes it does.  It grew up in the src directory.  We have a few more new apps other than mine so we decided it would come in real handy across the company.  So I lifted it out and up.

I don't think that just an include is going to work.  I think the directory needs its own .babel.rc, package.json, node_modules, to make this happen.  I'd be happy to be proven wrong, but that is where my thinking is at right now.  Cheers!

Comment: Do you use a babel.config.js file? What you most likely would benefit from is a top level babel.config.js, which affects all subdirectories. You can also use .babelrc files on an individual directory basis as well.

Comment: Teah, the 'mono project' idea.  I am not really into that as the .babel.rc as the 'One file to rule them all'.  Besides, on /disk/dev/ we have plenty of projects that aren't React/Babel. But thanks for the suggestion.  I think I am going to research how to build my utilities as private NPM modules so I can just install them where required.  Seems the easy way.  From the C/PHP world, a simple

include()

would have been nifty!